# How to access values from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

Just for example I have next NSDictionary

```
{      
        {
            "first_name" = Paul;
            "last_name" = Blabla;
            online = 0;

        },
        {
            "first_name" = Jess;
            "last_name" = BlaBlaBla;
            online = 0;

        },
}
```

when I use method `[myDictionary objectForKey:@"first_name"]` it always returning `(null)`,
my guess is that this is happening because I have more than one parameters that returns.

What can I do to return all "first_name"?

Comment: That output looks it comes from an array of dictionaries.  You should show some code as to how you're trying to access the string.

Comment: NSDictionary *friendsDictionary = [tempContainer yajl_JSON];

      NSString *firstName = [friendsDictionaryobjectForKey:@"first_name"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've shown in your post is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary (the outer punctuation should be parentheses not curly braces).  So, since it's an array, you have to get which object you're referring to first with objectAtIndex:, for instance, and then use object:forKey: to get the particular value you want.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you wanted to get all the names -- you can do that with valueForKey:@"first_name", which for an array of dictionaries will give you an array of all the names.  NSArray does not have an objectForKey: method.  This is assuming that you actually have an array.

Answer (score 2):

**Code :**

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in yourArray)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"first_name"]);
}
```

**Hint :**

What you have is an `array` of `NSDictionary` and NOT an NSDictionary. That's why it's been returning a `NULL` value...